# Android VideoView setAlpha() method like ImageView setAlpha()

Tags: android, sdk, android-videoview

Android `ImageView` have `setAlpha(float)` method but I know android `videoView` have no `setAlpha()` method because android `videoview` is `surfaecview` .

How can implement `setAlpha()` function in android `VideoView` like `imageview`.

Comment: You can do that with relativeLayout

Comment: My videoView in LinearLayout, if i setAlpha in LinearLayoutthen it work?

Comment: My Layout root view is relativeLayout and i also added in relativeLayout but it do not work?

Comment: <RelativeLayout> videoview, imgeview, otherview  </RelativeLayout> , do not work it.. , you have experience to do same work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
....
  <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="200dp">

      <VideoView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         .../>

      <View
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:alpha=".5"
              />

  </RelativeLayout>
....
```